# Jquery to get data from MySql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a calendar script that is displaying the information in the script under "events" I would simple like to let the script get the data from MySql but I tried in Dreamweaver and failed below is the script you will see there are only 4 fields ID; title; start and end. So I have a database called calendar but i am struggling to get it to work.

This site is made in Dreamweaver and is linked to a MySql server on Xampp on localhost. I simply need to pull the data from the database in order to replace the text under events.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2017-05-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2017-05-01'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: '2017-05-07',
                    end: '2017-05-10'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2017-05-09T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2017-05-16T16:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Conference',
                    start: '2017-05-11',
                    end: '2017-05-13'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2017-05-12T10:30:00',
                    end: '2017-05-12T12:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: '2017-05-12T12:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: '2017-05-12T14:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Happy Hour',
                    start: '2017-05-12T17:30:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Dinner',
                    start: '2017-05-12T20:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: '2017-05-13T07:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2017-05-28'
                }
            ]
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Where is the PHP code you've tried?

Comment: There's no php or mysql here. In turn, this makes the question unclear/too broad. Can you edit your question to contain the code for those?

Comment: Ok I am not sure how to put it on here I have a site on dreamweaver that I linked with Xampp and I have a table with 4 colums namely: ID; title; start and end. I dont know how to pull the data in those colums to display in the script under events

Comment: What is the #calendar element and where does the fullCalendar function come from? What do you mean by 'linked with Xampp'? If that's something you did with Dreamweaver, what series of actions did you take to create this link?

Comment: Also, when you add more useful info (like the fact that you're running an Xampp server) please edit your question instead of just placing it in a comment. This will make it easier for new people looking at your question to see all the details.